# latin-1 to ascii

Tags: python, unicode

I have a unicode string with accented latin chars e.g.

```
n=unicode('Wikipédia, le projet d’encyclopédie','utf-8')
```

I want to convert it to plain ascii i.e. 'Wikipedia, le projet dencyclopedie', so all acute/accent,cedilla etc should get removed

What is the fastest way to do that, as it needed to be done for matching a long autocomplete dropdown list

**Conclusion:**
As one my criteria is speed, Lennart's 'register your own error handler for unicode encoding/decoding' gives best result (see Alex's answer), speed difference increases further  as more and more chars are latin.

Here is the translation table I am using, also modified error handler as it need to take care of whole range of un-encoded char from error.start to error.end

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs

"""
This is more of visual translation also avoiding multiple char translation
e.g. £ may be written as {pound}
"""
latin_dict = {
u"¡": u"!", u"¢": u"c", u"£": u"L", u"¤": u"o", u"¥": u"Y",
u"¦": u"|", u"§": u"S", u"¨": u"`", u"©": u"c", u"ª": u"a",
u"«": u"<<", u"¬": u"-", u"­": u"-", u"®": u"R", u"¯": u"-",
u"°": u"o", u"±": u"+-", u"²": u"2", u"³": u"3", u"´": u"'",
u"µ": u"u", u"¶": u"P", u"·": u".", u"¸": u",", u"¹": u"1",
u"º": u"o", u"»": u">>", u"¼": u"1/4", u"½": u"1/2", u"¾": u"3/4",
u"¿": u"?", u"À": u"A", u"Á": u"A", u"Â": u"A", u"Ã": u"A",
u"Ä": u"A", u"Å": u"A", u"Æ": u"Ae", u"Ç": u"C", u"È": u"E",
u"É": u"E", u"Ê": u"E", u"Ë": u"E", u"Ì": u"I", u"Í": u"I",
u"Î": u"I", u"Ï": u"I", u"Ð": u"D", u"Ñ": u"N", u"Ò": u"O",
u"Ó": u"O", u"Ô": u"O", u"Õ": u"O", u"Ö": u"O", u"×": u"*",
u"Ø": u"O", u"Ù": u"U", u"Ú": u"U", u"Û": u"U", u"Ü": u"U",
u"Ý": u"Y", u"Þ": u"p", u"ß": u"b", u"à": u"a", u"á": u"a",
u"â": u"a", u"ã": u"a", u"ä": u"a", u"å": u"a", u"æ": u"ae",
u"ç": u"c", u"è": u"e", u"é": u"e", u"ê": u"e", u"ë": u"e",
u"ì": u"i", u"í": u"i", u"î": u"i", u"ï": u"i", u"ð": u"d",
u"ñ": u"n", u"ò": u"o", u"ó": u"o", u"ô": u"o", u"õ": u"o",
u"ö": u"o", u"÷": u"/", u"ø": u"o", u"ù": u"u", u"ú": u"u",
u"û": u"u", u"ü": u"u", u"ý": u"y", u"þ": u"p", u"ÿ": u"y", 
u"’":u"'"}

def latin2ascii(error):
    """
    error is  protion of text from start to end, we just convert first
    hence return error.start+1 instead of error.end
    """
    return latin_dict[error.object[error.start]], error.start+1

codecs.register_error('latin2ascii', latin2ascii)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = u"¼ éíñ§ÐÌëÑ » ¼ ö ® © ’"
    print x
    print x.encode('ascii', 'latin2ascii')
```

**Why I return `error.start + 1`:**

error object returned can be multiple characters, and we convert only first of these e.g. if I add `print error.start, error.end` to error handler output is

```
¼ éíñ§ÐÌëÑ » ¼ ö ® © ’
0 1
2 10
3 10
4 10
5 10
6 10
7 10
8 10
9 10
11 12
13 14
15 16
17 18
19 20
21 22
1/4 einSDIeN >> 1/4 o R c '
```

so in second line we get chars from 2-10 but we convert only 2nd hence return 3 as continue point, if we return error.end output is

```
¼ éíñ§ÐÌëÑ » ¼ ö ® © ’
0 1
2 10
11 12
13 14
15 16
17 18
19 20
21 22
1/4 e >> 1/4 o R c '
```

As we can see 2-10 portion has been replaced by a single char. off-course it would be faster to just encode whole range in one go and return error.end, but for demonstration purpose I have kept it simple.

see http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error for more details

Comment: I'm sure you're aware, but take care not to show these ascii-fied strings to the user. The meaning of a word can change totally when you change the letters around more or less at random (making 'ö' into 'o' and so on).

Comment: yes this is not for display but for typing, we have a on screen keyboard with ascii letters problem is how user will type é or õ, so if types e, it should match string having e, é, ê etc

Comment: I don't understand your substitution of `error.start+1` for `error.end`.  Can you please explain?  Both seem to work the same for me.

Comment: @gorus I have added the reason in question

Comment: Know that replacing certain characters can [get somebody killed](http://gizmodo.com/382026/a-cellphones-missing-dot-kills-two-people-puts-three-more-in-jail)

Comment: look for `Unihandecode`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So here are three approaches, more or less as given or suggested in other answers:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import unicodedata

x = u"Wikipédia, le projet d’encyclopédie"

xtd = {ord(u'’'): u"'", ord(u'é'): u'e', }

def asciify(error):
    return xtd[ord(error.object[error.start])], error.end

codecs.register_error('asciify', asciify)

def ae():
  return x.encode('ascii', 'asciify')

def ud():
  return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')

def tr():
  return x.translate(xtd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print 'or:', x
  print 'ae:', ae()
  print 'ud:', ud()
  print 'tr:', tr()
```

Run as main, this emits:

```
or: Wikipédia, le projet d’encyclopédie
ae: Wikipedia, le projet d'encyclopedie
ud: Wikipedia, le projet dencyclopedie
tr: Wikipedia, le projet d'encyclopedie
```

showing clearly that the unicodedata-based approach, while it does have the convenience of not needing a translation map `xtd`, can't translate all characters properly in an automated fashion (it works for accented letters but not for the reverse-apostrophe), so it would also need some auxiliary step to deal explicitly with those (no doubt before what's now its body).

Performance is also interesting. On my laptop with Mac OS X 10.5 and system Python 2.5, quite repeatably:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import a' 'a.ae()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.5 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import a' 'a.ud()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.66 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import a' 'a.tr()'
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.4 usec per loop
```

`translate` is surprisingly slow (relative to the other approaches). I believe the issue is that the dict is looked into for every character in the `translate` case (and most are not there), but only for those few characters that ARE there with the `asciify` approach.

So for completeness here's "beefed-up unicodedata" approach:

```
specstd = {ord(u'’'): u"'", }
def specials(error):
  return specstd.get(ord(error.object[error.start]), u''), error.end
codecs.register_error('specials', specials)

def bu():
  return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ASCII', 'specials')
```

this gives the right output, BUT:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import a' 'a.bu()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 usec per loop
```

...speed isn't all that good any more.  So, if speed matters, it's no doubt worth the trouble of making a complete `xtd` translation dict and using the `asciify` approach. When a few extra microseconds per translation are no big deal, one might want to consider the `bu` approach simply for its convenience (only needs a translation dict for, hopefully few, special characters that don't translate correctly with the underlying unicodedata idea).

Comment: Thanks for the summary and timing them :)

Comment: is there a reason behind doing 'ord' while creating dict and again getting ordinal while asciifying ?

Comment: @Anurag, the reason the dict's that way is to make it immediately usable in `.translate` -- `asciify` of course doesn't need that. The simplification reduces its timing, roughly, from 7.5 to 7.3 usec.

Answer (score 11):

The awesome [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/) module does this for you:

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> n = unicode('Wikipédia, le projet d’encyclopédie','utf-8')
>>> unidecode.unidecode(n)
"Wikipedia, le projet d'encyclopedie"
```

Answer (score 8):

The "correct" way to do this is to register your own error handler for unicode encoding/decoding, and in that error handler provide the replacements from è to e and ö to o, etc.

Like so:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs

map = {u'é': u'e',
       u'’': u"'",
       # ETC
       }

def asciify(error):
    return map[error.object[error.start]], error.end

codecs.register_error('asciify', asciify)

test = u'Wikipédia, le projet d’encyclopédie'
print test.encode('ascii', 'asciify')
```

You might also find something in IBM's [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library and it's Python bindings [PyICU](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/0.8.1), though, it might be less work.

Comment: +1: I would just add some more checking on the input for the asciify function, but I think this is also a very quick and good reference for custom error handling in unicode encoding.

Comment: I agree this is the correct implementation. Maybe someone can suggest a full mapping for general-purpose use.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer but I think I would be choosing the Alex's answer for being complete and that included timings.

Comment: also asciify should convert all char from error.start to error.end

Answer (score 1):

[Maketrans](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) (and translate) then convert to ascii:

```
intab = u'áéí'  # extend as needed
outtab = u'aei' # as well as this one
table = maketrans(intab, outtab)

text = translate(u"Wikipédia, le projet d’encyclopédie", table)

try:
    temp = unicode(text, "utf-8")
    fixed = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', temp).encode('ASCII', action)
    return fixed
except Exception, errorInfo:
    print errorInfo
    print "Unable to convert the Unicode characters to xml character entities"
    raise errorInfo
```

(from [here](http://techxplorer.com/2006/07/18/converting-unicode-to-ascii-using-python/))

Comment: But this will convert them to xml character entities. That's not what he asked for.

Comment: I do not understand first line of the solution  "Maketrans (and translate) then convert to ascii:" why that is needed and you do not use it anywhere in code?

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: Then it encodes them in ASCII.
@Anurag Uniyal: He wanted to replace e.g. 'é' with 'e' which a plain conversion wouldn't do for him. This is why maketrans is needed. The code snippet I copied here only shows the unicode->ASCII conversion.

Comment: I added the maketrans example.

Comment: @sztomi:Thing here is that he wants non-ascii characters to be translated to ascii characters, which your example doesn't do. Your maketrans example doesn't even use unicode...

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: Look at this line: `fixed = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', temp).encode('ASCII', action)`. And maketrans works with unicode as well.

Comment: @ sztomi but wouldn't  unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', temp).encode('ASCII', 'ignore') is enought it will also convert é to e

Comment: The translate method of Unicode strings doesn't work this way (and doesn't need maketrans): you're confusing it with the same-name method of `str` objects, which DOES work roughly as you say (needing `string.maketrans` to build a table).

Comment: Ah, you mean "action" to be "'ignore'". I see. Then it works in fact. Your translate example still doesn't work though. I think you should try your own examples out.

Answer (score 1):

Package [`unihandecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unihandecode) is

> US-ASCII transliterations of Unicode text.
>   an improved version of Python unidecode, that is Python port of Text::Unidecode Perl module by Sean M. Burke .

```
pip install Unihandecode
```

then in `python`

```
import unihandecode
print(unihandecode.unidecode(u'Wikipédia, le projet d’encyclopédie'))
```

prints `Wikipedia, le projet d'encyclopedie`.

Answer (score 0):

Without measuring, I would expect that the .translate method of Unicode strings is the fastest solution. You should definitely make your own measurements, though.