# Can not remove french letters in a string returned by Python glob

Tags: python

I would like to rename files with french letters. I am using glob to browse the files and a function I've found on the Internet to remove the french letters. The `supprime_accent` seems to work ok. However, it doesn't rename files returned by the glob function.

Does anybody knows what can be the reason? Is it related with glob encoding?

```
def supprime_accent(ligne):
    """ supprime les accents du texte source """
    accents = { 'a': ['à', 'ã', 'á', 'â'],
                'e': ['é', 'è', 'ê', 'ë'],
                'i': ['î', 'ï'],
                'u': ['ù', 'ü', 'û'],
                'o': ['ô', 'ö'] }
    for (char, accented_chars) in accents.iteritems():
        for accented_char in accented_chars:
            ligne = ligne.replace(accented_char, char)
    return ligne

for file_name in glob.glob("attachments/*.jpg"):
    print supprime_accent(file_name)
```

Comment: I believe every single letter in the english alphabet is a "french letter", is it not ?

Comment: yes I guess :) Sorry for my bad english. how would you call 'é' 'à' 'è'...? accent letters?

Comment: The technical term (surely a household word, no??) is "diacritics".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two potential problems here.

First, you need to use unicode strings in your source code, and you need to [tell Python what encoding the source code is in](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding). Unfortunately doing it right doubles the number of vowels in your table... :-\

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
...
accents = { u'a': [u'à', u'ã', u'á', u'â'],
            u'e': [u'é', u'è', u'ê', u'ë'],
            u'i': [u'î', u'ï'],
            u'u': [u'ù', u'ü', u'û'],
            u'o': [u'ô', u'ö'] }
```

Second, I think you need to convert the filename returned by `glob` to a unicode string.

```
import sys
file_name = file_name.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

Python 3.0 fixed both these problems: filenames don't have to be decoded and unicode strings don't need a `u` tag.

Answer (score 1):

try this question and answers to it, in question I have given the final solution I am using
[latin-1 to ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382998/latin-1-to-ascii)

and pass a unicode string to glob, to get unicode file names back e.g.

```
for file_name in glob.glob(u"attachments/*.jpg"):
    print file_name.encode('ascii', 'latin2ascii')
```

Comment: That'ok if you have unicode string but that's not what is returned by glog.glob and unicode(file_name) raises an error

Comment: @luc glob does return unicode, >>> glob.glob(u"c:\\windows")
[u'c:\\windows']

Answer (score 1):

I've succeed to fix the problem by converting file_name to unicode with cp1252 enncoding.

```
for file_name in glob.glob("attachments/*.jpg"):
    file_name = file_name.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    print unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', file_name).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Edit: Jason gave a better solution by replacing unicode(file_name, 'cp1252') with file_name.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())