# scan through a list with dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi i have been trying this for some time now no result yet. 
i have a `dict = {'Å':'a', 'Ä':'a', 'Ö':'0', 'å':'a', 'ä':'a', 'ö':'o'}`

```
 input = lxml.etree.parse(inputxml)
 for block in input.xpath('//PAGE/BLOCK/TEXT'):
    J = block.xpath('TOKEN/text()')
    current = 0
    line = ""
    while current < len(J):
        A = J[current]
        current += 1
```

i need to scan A with the dict and find the non-english letters and replace it with english letter

```
   for i in A:
        if(dict.has_key(i)):
              ReplaceWord= A.replace(i,dict[i])
```

but this is not working

Comment: 0%? Did you really like *none* of the answers you've received?

Comment: There are many questions on SO dealing with something like this.  The most complete seems Alex Martellis answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382998/latin-1-to-ascii.

Comment: It is not that i did no like an of the ans i am new to python i just dnt know how implement the ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not what you asked about, but it looks like you might be interested in it: [Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) is a module specifically intended to reduce any series of characters to the most similar ASCII characters.

```
>>> import unidecode # to install: `pip install unidecode`
>>> line = u"Flyttbara hyllplan anpassar förvaringen så"
>>> unidecode.unidecode(line)
u'Flyttbara hyllplan anpassar forvaringen sa'
```

Answer (score 2):

`translate` is what you need.

```
d=str.maketrans('ÅÄÖåäö','aaoaao')
s.translate(d)
```

Comment: This code is Python 3.x specific. It won't work on Python 2.x

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: the fix for py2k is trivial, isn't it?

Comment: @SilentGhost: The simplest fix I can think of is: `unicode_line.translate(dict(zip(map(ord, u'ÅÄÖåäö'), u'aaoaao')))`. I wouldn't call it trivial. I don't see how to do `.translate()` in this case for bytestrings in an arbitrary encoding  (without converting to unicode).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: `string.maketrans` do exist in python2.

Comment: And how do you propose to use it in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Both in python 3 and 2.x:

```
letters = {'Å':'a', 'Ä':'a', 'Ö':'0', 'å':'a', 'ä':'a', 'ö':'o'}
line = "Flyttbara hyllplan anpassar förvaringen så"
for c in letters:
    line = line.replace(c, letters[c])
```

Comment: When i tried this for some char i get UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)