# Possible to do a string replace with a dictionary?

Tags: python

I would like to change all accented characters into non-accented characters:

```
 conversion_dict = {"ä": "a", "ö": "o", "ü": "u","Ä": "A", "Ö": "O", "Ü": "U",
                   "á": "a", "à": "a", "â": "a", "é": "e", "è": "e", "ê": "e",
                   "ú": "u", "ù": "u", "û": "u", "ó": "o", "ò": "o", "ô": "o",
                   "Á": "A", "À": "A", "Â": "A", "É": "E", "È": "E", "Ê": "E",
                   "Ú": "U", "Ù": "U", "Û": "U", "Ó": "O", "Ò": "O", "Ô": "O","ß": "s"}
```

Is there a way to do something like `"paragraph of text".replace([conversion_dict])`?

Comment: What you have shown is not "all". What is the purpose? Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: I believe there's something in the Python standard library for doing this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**preferred method using third-party module**

A much better alternative than the method below is to use the awesome [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/) module:

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> somestring = u"äüÊÂ"
>>> unidecode.unidecode(somestring)
'auEA'
```

**built-in, slightly-hazardous method**

Inferring from your question that you are looking to normalize unicode characters, there is actually a nice, built-in way to do this:

```
>>> somestring = u"äüÊÂ"
>>> somestring
u'\xe4\xfc\xca\xc2'
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', somestring).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'auEA'
```

Check out the documentation for [unicodedata.normalize](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).

Note, however, that there might be some issues with this. See [this post](http://www.j-schell.de/node/269) for a nice explanation and some workarounds.

See also, [latin-1-to-ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382998/latin-1-to-ascii) for alternatives.

Comment: This is a horrid kludge. It uses unintended side-effects and doesn't do the whole job, once the requirements stray into the real world of asciifying Latin-n text.

Comment: @JohnMachin could you please elaborate or provide a link so I can learn more about that?

Comment: @JohnMachin or could you suggest a better alternative rather than just downvoting?

Answer (score 5):

```
for k, v in conversion_dict.items():
    txt = txt.replace(k, v)
```

ETA: This isn't "horribly" slow at all. Here's a timer for a toy case, where we're replacing a 100000 character string using a dictionary that has mappings of 56 characters in it where none of the characters are in the string:

```
import timeit

NUM_REPEATS = 100000

conversion_dict = dict([(chr(i), "C") for i in xrange(100)])

txt = "A" * 100000

def replace(x):
    for k, v in conversion_dict.items():
        x = x.replace(k, v)

t = timeit.Timer("replace(txt)", setup="from __main__ import replace, txt")
print t.timeit(NUM_REPEATS) / NUM_REPEATS, "sec / call"
```

On my computer I get the running time

```
0.0056938188076 sec / call
```

So one two-hundredth of a second for a 100,000 character string. Now, some of the characters actually will be in the string, and this will slow it down, but in almost any reasonable situation the replaced characters will be much rarer than other characters. Still, jterrace's answer is perfect.

Comment: That depends on the length of the string and of the dictionary.

Comment: If the `replace()` did not replace anything, it will return the original string you passed in.  If it does have to replace something, it will have to *copy* the whole string (strings are immutable).  Since this does not happen at all in your example code, your timings are not that meaningful.  (Anyway, timings are usually only meaningful when you *compare* two different approaches.)

Comment: Yes, the time would be `O(len(s) * len(d))`

Comment: Sven: At most, it would have to make as many copies as there are pairs of letters to replace. I'd also say that timings *are* meaningful in terms of descriptions like "horribly slow." At the very least, they can tell you when optimizations might be premature.

Answer (score 4):

This is a VFAQ. See e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382998/latin-1-to-ascii) or google "python asciify" or "python unaccent".

To produce a decent dictionary for use with `unicode.translate`, you need an approach that will automatically discover the easy cases, and find the ones where you need to make a manual entry. A good approach is to hurtle through the BMP looking at what is produced by `unicodedata.name(the_ordinal, "")`.

Automatic discovery: `re.match("LATIN (SMALL|CAPTTAL) LETTER ([A-Z]) WITH ", name)`

Otherwise if you get a match with `"LATIN (SMALL|CAPTTAL) LETTER [A-Z].+"`, you need a manual entry.

**Important note**: `unicode.translate` uses a "mapping of Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, ***Unicode strings*** or None" ... so you can replace e.g. capital THORN by "Th".

Here's why using `unicodedata.normalize` isn't a good idea:

Characters whose normalisation's first character is NOT in the ASCII range are stripped out. This includes not only all punctuation (which you may not care about) but letters that are NOT "accented" e.g. `ß`

```
>>> from unicodedata import name, normalize
>>> for i in range(0xA0, 0x100):
...     c = unichr(i)
...     a = normalize('NFKD', c).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
...     if not a:
...         print("FAIL: U+%04X %s" % (i, name(c)))
...
FAIL: U+00A1 INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK
FAIL: U+00A2 CENT SIGN
FAIL: U+00A3 POUND SIGN
FAIL: U+00A4 CURRENCY SIGN
FAIL: U+00A5 YEN SIGN
FAIL: U+00A6 BROKEN BAR
FAIL: U+00A7 SECTION SIGN
FAIL: U+00A9 COPYRIGHT SIGN
FAIL: U+00AB LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
FAIL: U+00AC NOT SIGN
FAIL: U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN
FAIL: U+00AE REGISTERED SIGN
FAIL: U+00B0 DEGREE SIGN
FAIL: U+00B1 PLUS-MINUS SIGN
FAIL: U+00B5 MICRO SIGN
FAIL: U+00B6 PILCROW SIGN
FAIL: U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT
FAIL: U+00BB RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
FAIL: U+00BF INVERTED QUESTION MARK
FAIL: U+00C6 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE
FAIL: U+00D0 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH
FAIL: U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN
FAIL: U+00D8 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE
FAIL: U+00DE LATIN CAPITAL LETTER THORN
FAIL: U+00DF LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S <<<<<<<<<<========== ß
FAIL: U+00E6 LATIN SMALL LETTER AE
FAIL: U+00F0 LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH
FAIL: U+00F7 DIVISION SIGN
FAIL: U+00F8 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE
FAIL: U+00FE LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work? I haven't tried it out, but it seems like a simple solution.

```
for key in string:
    if key in dict:
        string = string.replace(key, dict[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Any solution ignoring the source encoding and the input encoding will be formally correct, but  it can easily fail doing its job.

You should first be sure you know the encoding of the input, then you should map it into the encoding you wronte the map in, and then everything could be fine. You could use as internal encoding unicode and convert the *known* input encoding into it.

Try [reading this](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) about the matter.