# python convert unicode into it's "print" form

Tags: python, unicode

I grabbed this paragraph in a webpage:

> It doesn’t look like a controversial new case management system is going anywhere. So the city plans to spend the next few months helping local social assistance workers learn to live with it.

and in my downloaded html data in python unicode it looks like this:

```
mystr = u'It doesn\u2019t look lake a controversial new case management system is going anywhere. So\xa0the city plans to spend the next few months helping local social assistance workers learn to live with it.'
```

my plan is to be able to use something like `mystr.find("doesn't")` to find the location of the word. Currently, the `mystr.find("doesn't")` will return `-1` as it is actually `doesn\u2019t` in `mystr`

Is there a fast way to convert `mystr` to exactly what the paragraph looked like above, so that all unicode 'characters' are replaced by 'normal' characters so that I can use `str.find()`?

The best posts I've found on the webpage so far is to replace the `u'\u2019'` with `"'"` and then replace `u'\xa0'` with `' '`. Is there are more convenient method so that I don't have to really write a method and build a conversion dictionary?

ps:

I've also tried unicodedata.normalizing and stuff like that, doesn't seem to work.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention, the python version is 2.7

Comment: "Exactly what it looks like above" is not "doesn't", it's "doesn’t" (note the "curly quote" used for the apostrophe).  There's no general way to know what "simpler" characters you want to convert other characters into, although there are probably libraries that may try to make various guesses.  ([This](http://ftfy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) seems to have quote-uncurling abilities.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [latin-1 to ascii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382998/latin-1-to-ascii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have what the webpage contains. `\u2019` is [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+2019), a *fancy* single quote, but you are using a simple ASCII single quote instead, e.g. the lowly [U+0027 APOSTROPHE](http://codepoints.net/U+0027).

If you print the value, you'll see it produces something that looks a lot like it has a singe quote in it, but slightly *curved*:

```
>>> mystr = u'It doesn\u2019t look lake a controversial new case management system is going anywhere. So\xa0the city plans to spend the next few months helping local social assistance workers learn to live with it.'
>>> print mystr
It doesn’t look lake a controversial new case management system is going anywhere. So the city plans to spend the next few months helping local social assistance workers learn to live with it.
```

All Python did was echo the *representation* of the string, which replaces anything non-printable and non-ASCII with escape sequences that make the value *reproducible*; you can copy and paste the value into any Python interpreter or script and it'll produce the same value. Because the default source encoding for Python is ASCII only ASCII characters are used to describe the value.

You could look for that text instead:

```
>>> u'doesn\u2019t' in mystr
True
```

or you could use a library like [`unidecode`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unidecode) to replace non-ASCII codepoints with ASCII 'lookalikes'; it'll replace the fancy quote with a plain ASCII quote:

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(mystr)
"It doesn't look lake a controversial new case management system is going anywhere. So the city plans to spend the next few months helping local social assistance workers learn to live with it."
>>> "doesn't" in unidecode(mystr)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

its because of that its not `doesn't` but its `doesn’t` the quote is a unicode so if you use `doesn’t` python raise `UnicodeDecodeError`  . so you need to add `u` at the leading of your string with `doesn’t`

```
>>> mystr.find("doesn’t")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> mystr.find(u"doesn’t")
3
```