# How do I convert decorated latin unicode characters to plain latin in python

Tags: python, unicode

Unicode specifies a bunch of [modifications you can make to latin characters](https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_1F100.html). How can I convert these unicode characters to vanilla latin characters in python?

To be clear, I'm not asking how to get rid of accents from letters. I'm asking how to convert things that have linguistically the same meaning, but some decorated display, like negative, encircled, enclosed in a box types of displays.

For example, how I do I convert

> °° c

to

> °ORIGINAL° c

(Stripping those non-language characters will be a separate task)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't perfect, but what you're looking for is something like [Unicode Decomposition](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.1.0/ch03.pdf#G729). The concept of Unicode normalization and decomposition is a book of its own.

For something quick and dirty, fortunately, Python has this [built-in for you](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)!

```py
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', '°° c')
'°ORIGINAL° c'
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to make a conversion map yourself.
Something like:

`conversion_map = {'': 'o', '': 'r', '': 'i'}`

I am not aware of a simple logical way to convert these values... but somebody feel free to correct me.

You can also look here for other ideas.
[latin-1 to ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382998/latin-1-to-ascii)

Comment: [Alyssa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57618242/4518341) is probably the best solution, but FWIW, it's easier with `str.maketrans` and `str.translate`, e.g. `trans = str.maketrans('', 'ABC'); ''.translate(trans)` -> `'ABBA'`

Answer (score 1):

Even though I accepted Alyssa Haroldsen's answer, I also wanted to provide an alternative that addresses what I really wanted. If I keep only letter characters, I not only strip out modifier characters, but I get rid of all kinds of non-letter characters (like emoji's and math symbols).

I was afraid I would end up stripping out kanji or other non-latin characters, but apparently all languages' characters are considered letters by the unicode standard

```
# only keep letters, which apparently includes all kinds of languages https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Lo
keep_categories = ('Ll', 'Lm', 'Lo', 'Lt', 'Lu', 'Zs')
filtered_string  = ' '.join(''.join(filter(lambda c: unicodedata.category(c) in keep_categories, w)) for w in words)
```

Comment: As a tip, changing `keep_categories` to a set may speed things up.

Comment: Hmm, you have me wondering actually. I've seen search algorithms for small sets perform better with linear time algorithms than log algorithms. But in this case the match set is small but the number of items being matched against it is large. I guess that makes it O(M log(N)) with M >> N. I can't quite figure it out analytically, but I'd be really curios to see what an actual profiling result returns. What are your thoughts? Thanks for mentioning it! Performance is definitely important for a function working on unknown-length strings!

Comment: I'm thinking in a Big-O sense you're definitely right. M*log(6) is much less than M*6 :D Thanks for the suggestion!